# AttributeError: 'Rectangle' object has no property 'norm_hist' - python

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am reviewing the matpoltlib and seaborn packages. I know this question is a little below the level of stack but no one can give me a solid answer about this error. I am using displot to make histograms and the notes are trying to show the difference between it displaying w/ count vs. density. Using the "iris" dataset w/in seaborn the first example is:

```
[IN]: sns.displot(iris["sepal_length"], kde=False) 
[OUT]: histogram, no curve, count on the y-axis
```

The next example uses "norm_hist" and is supposed to change the counts to densities and I am getting an error I don't understand?

```
[IN]: sns.displot(iris["sepal_length"], norm_hist=True, kde=False)
[OUT]: Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\cyrra\OneDrive\Documents\HDS 802 - Programming in Healthcare (Python & R)\Module 7 Python\M7P - MINE.py", line 79, in <module>
    sns.displot(iris["sepal_length"], norm_hist=True, kde=False)

  File "C:\Users\cyrra\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\seaborn\distributions.py", line 2227, in displot
    p.plot_univariate_histogram(**hist_kws)

  File "C:\Users\cyrra\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\seaborn\distributions.py", line 555, in plot_univariate_histogram
    artists = plot_func(

  File "C:\Users\cyrra\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 1438, in inner
    return func(ax, *map(sanitize_sequence, args), **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\cyrra\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py", line 2488, in bar
    r.update(kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\cyrra\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 996, in update
    raise AttributeError(f"{type(self).__name__!r} object "

AttributeError: 'Rectangle' object has no property 'norm_hist'
```

Can someone explain this to me? I am looking through the documentation for seaborn and I can't seem to find these options. Were they deprecated? Unfortunately the material provided for my python class in my MS is from 2017 and they won't update it.

Thank you

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had this same error and my solution was
changing `ffn/core.py`  (it was the first file in the error list, your file is different I see, but same principle norm something must be deprecated?)

from

```
ax = ser.hist(bins=bins, figsize=figsize, normed=True, **kwargs)
```

to

```
ax = ser.hist(bins=bins, figsize=figsize, density=True, **kwargs)
```

point being: changing the normed to density
i.e. here norm_hist to density

Answer (score 4):

According to the [documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.displot.html#seaborn.displot), `displot` indeed does not have this parameter.

your are confused with the deprecated `distplot` function ([here](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.distplot.html)) that has it.

Comment: Correct that `displot` does not have that exact parameter, but it exposes the same functionality (with additional forms of normalization) through the `stat` parameter. So `displot(..., stat="density")` is equivalent to `distplot(..., norm_hist=True)`.

Comment: (To be more clear, it is [`histplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.histplot.html) that has a `stat` parameter; it gets passed through as part of the `kwargs` if you supply it to `displot`.

Answer (score 0):

You must use density insted of normed for errors as 'rectangle' object has no property 'normed'

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: OK.So,I can express chapter as a problem observing frequently among parametric string errors considering individual experiments completely

Comment: I will suggest discussing an option as ,density=True,  among string parameters

Comment: Generally speaking, one-sentence answers are generally poor quality. You should provide a lot more context to your answer.